# Default search parameters for Finder

Tags: macos, finder

I'm wondering if there are any hidden prefs (to be read via `defaults`) that would alter default search parameters for Finder.

Currently search string is searched in contents of a file (by default). Is there a way to alter it to search in file name?

[image: Search in Finder]

Comment: This has changed - in the way you would like it to work - from Leopard to Snow Leopard. It has been a gripe a lot of people had (incl. me). I know this does not answer your question, so it's only a comment.

Comment: +1 - When I want to search for content, it is usually spontaneous, from any app, so I use the Spotlight shortcut (command-space)

When I am in finder, it is usually to manipulate a specific file. I know the file name, I just don't know where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google turned up a promising link

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050501162147222

I'll try to sort out the steps and post something simple, here.

Comment: Has anybody got that to work on 10.6? I haven't. I have another idea for a solution, I need to play with it a bit, but I'll probably be back to post an answer soon :)

Comment: @cwd I couldn't get it to work on 10.6 either. But I just added updated instructions to [osx - Make search by file name default in Finder - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/214012/make-search-by-file-name-default-in-finder/264879#264879).