# How to select the "File Name" radio box with Applescript GUI

Tags: macos, automation, finder, applescript

I'm running OS X 10.6 and I want to use applescript to click on the "File Name" radio button of the finder window when the search is open. (It defaults to "Contents")

I used the UI Browser (below) and came up with a path, but Applescript is giving me some errors so I must be doing something wrong. I've posted my code and screen shots below:

**Code:**

```
tell application "System Events"
    activate application "Finder"
    click checkbox "File Name" of radio group 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 of application "Finder"
end tell
```

**Screen Cap:**

[image]

**Code From UIElementInspector**

```
<AXApplication: “Finder”>
 <AXWindow: “Searching “UIElementInspector””>
  <AXSplitGroup>
   <AXGroup>
    <AXRadioGroup>
     <AXCheckBox: “File Name”>

Attributes:
   AXRole:  “AXCheckBox”
   AXRoleDescription:  “check box”
   AXHelp:  “(null)”
   AXValue:  “1”
   AXEnabled:  “1”
   AXFocused (W):  “0”
   AXParent:  “<AXRadioGroup>”
   AXWindow:  “<AXWindow: “Searching “UIElementInspector””>”
   AXTopLevelUIElement:  “<AXWindow: “Searching “UIElementInspector””>”
   AXPosition:  “x=1357 y=149”
   AXSize:  “w=75 h=17”
   AXTitle:  “File Name”

Actions:
   AXPress - press
```

Comment: Somewhat related: [osx - Make search by file name default in Finder - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/214012/make-search-by-file-name-default-in-finder/264879#264879).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more retarded UI scripting:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set frontmost to true
    click menu bar 1's menu bar item "File"'s menu 1's menu item "Find"
    tell application "Finder"
        set toolbar visible of window 1 to false
        set bounds of window 1 to {0, 22, 960, 587}
    end tell
    tell window 1's splitter group 1
        click group 1's radio group 2's checkbox "File Name"
        click group 1's radio group 1's radio button "This Mac"
        click scroll area 1's outline 1's group 1's button 1 -- sort by Name
        click group 2's pop up button 1
        keystroke "sys" & return
        click group 2's pop up button 2
        keystroke "are " & return
    end tell
end tell
```

For some reason, on my 10.6.7 `checkbox "File Name"` is in `radio group 2` instead of `radio group 1`.

Comment: Thanks! This did what I wanted it to, (actually a lot more than I wanted it to!) and it was very easy to just drop this in and start using it, so I'm going to mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @cwd Yeah, I just added the extra stuff as examples of GUI scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Scripted UI operations can't be communicated to `application`s directly; they must go to an `application process`, in this case `application process "Finder"` as distinct from `application "Finder"`.  [More information](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html)

BTW, Apple has [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) to do that exploration, instead of using a trial commercial program that may eventually time out or cease working.

Comment: Could you give an example of the syntax I would use to do the first part of your suggestion?

Comment: Just replacing `application "Finder"` with `application process "Finder"` should work, although it might be necessary to get a more direct handle from System Events (`tell application "System Events" to set app to first application process whose name is "Finder"` or similar).

Comment: BTW I have a (still in development/debugging) Automator workflow that does quite a lot of UI hacking; see http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~allbery/Edit-Text-Field-In-Emacs.workflow.zip.

Comment: looks like a broken link, but I'd still love to see it.

Comment: Sorry, case-o.  http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~allbery/Edit-Text-Field-in-Emacs.workflow.zip works.

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed how the search works again and now it's very convoluted to search by file name, you have to click an auto-hiding dropdown that disappears when you hit enter. The only way to get the dropdown back is to delete a letter and re-type it.

Anyway, the following AppleScript worked for me:

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
    set frontmost to true
        click menu bar 1's menu bar item "File"'s menu 1's menu item "Find"
        tell application "Finder"
    end tell
    tell window 1's splitter group 1
            click group 2's pop up button 1
            click menu item "Name" of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 2
            click group 2's pop up button 2
            click menu item "contains" of menu 1 of pop up button 2 of group 2
    end tell
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

I wonder if there's a way in applescript to automatically prepend "name:" to searches so that we don't have to always use command-F to search by name?